# Loading data grid in dojo during runtime

Tags: datagrid, dojo, runtime, treegrid

I'm building a web-application in JavaScript using the dojo framework. I want to create new tabs during runtime (I have a TabPane and add ContentPanes) and want to create data grids in that Panes. (Specificly LazyTreeGrids but they extend the data grid class so it should be the same)

When I do this I get several errors:

```
ReferenceError
../dojo-release-1.7.2-src/dojo/_base/Deferred.js:216
Error parsing in _ContentSetter#Setter_dijit_layout_ContentPane_0_0 
ReferenceError
../dojo-release-1.7.2-src/dijit/layout/ContentPane.js:543
Error undefined running custom onLoad code: This deferred has already been resolved
```

When I run the TabPane without the data grid or if I run the data grid without the TabPane (and at page load) it works just fine. Do you have any ideas how I could solve my problem?

The relevant code:

```
 dojo.ready(function(){
    var tabPanel = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
        style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"
    }, "mainWindow");

    //console.error("tset");
    var console = new contentPane.console("test");  


    var cp1 = new dojox.layout.ContentPane({
         title: "HomeScreen",
         content: ""
    });

    tabPanel.addChild(cp1);

    var cp2 = new dojox.layout.ContentPane({
         title: "+",
        content: ""
    });
    tabPanel.addChild(cp2);

    tabPanel.startup();

    require(["dojo/dom-attr"], function(domAttr){
        domAttr.set(cp1, "content", console.getContent() );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure the pane is loaded before starting the grid.
Note that you could have the grid being the direct child of the TabContainer.
tabContainer.addChild(myGrid);

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest in my problem. I want to use a contentPane containing the grid so that I can add some buttons to it as well. I tried to initialize the contentPane before loading the grid but either I do it wrong or the error has another reason. I add the relevant code above.

Comment: I think dojox.layout.ContentPane are part of the problem... could you try with plain old dijit.layout.ContentPane and tell me how it goes?

Comment: I use the dojox pane because dijit pane has problems excecuting scripts. But I changed that to test the difference as you asked me and it seems to be exactily the error output.

Comment: Everything seems to indicate that the deferred had a problem. In your network panel you don't have an error sent?

Comment: No, everything is loaded with "200 - OK". I just put the add content code for cp1 in a button so it will defenetly added after cp1 is created but the error is still there. I have the feeling, that somehow  the grid uses "onLoad" and can't do it since onLoad was called before. Is that possible?

Comment: The thing is the grid needs the CP to be completely loaded to be added to the CP's containerNode. So after the ContentPane onLoad. You'll need to start the grid manually then. If, you create the grid, but don't start it, for it to work it needs to be included in the CP's content property before the CP is started

Comment: Here is an example with a basic prototype : http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/2bf55/3

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I understand you. My ContentPane is fully loaded (with an empty String as its content) and set to its containerNode. I add my grid using "<div id='grid1' jsid='grid1' dojoType='dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid' structure='layout' treeModel='model'></div>". I added that grid by clicking on a button so I'm sure everything loaded completely. Do you mean my approach with the div-Tag is the problem and I should only use an object? (The reason I don't is that I had problems with my grid before, but if that is a likely reason for my problem I will see into that.)

Comment: I saw your example just yet, that looks like what I want to do, thanks for that! I will look into it right now.

Comment: That was the trick! My problem was the div-tag containing the grid. Thank you very much for your generous help.

Comment: You are most welcome :) Happy it helped at least a little! ;)